# SSH is blocked to only a specific SSH client on the same VPN network

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn

**In short**

On the same VPN connection, Android can connect to an SSH server, but Macbook can't.

**Detail**

Network is configured as the following figure:

[image]

Macbook and Android want to connect to an SSH server. Since the server is behind a campus firewall, L2TP/IPsec server is running on the same machine on which the SSH server is running.

Both can connect to the VPN server.

But only Android can connect to the SSH server. Macbook can't. `ssh -v <ssh server>` on Macbook gives:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to <ssh server> [<ssh server>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <ssh server> port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host <ssh server> port 22: Operation timed out
```

On the SSH server, `sudo netstat -peanut | grep ssh` gives:

```
tcp    0    0    0.0.0.0::22    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    0    1986196    6194/sshd
```

That's strange.

Finally, I tested `nmap -p 22 <ssh server>` on both Macbook and Android (Android app Termux is used):

- Macbook

  ```
  Host is up (0.018s latency).
  PORT   STATE    SERVICE
  22/tcp filtered ssh
  ```
- Android

  ```
  Host is up (0.026s latency).
  PORT   STATE    SERVICE
  22/tcp open     ssh
  ```

The VPN and SSH server is managed by me and I haven't block Macbook on the server (and I even don't know how to do it)

In such a situation, what can I test to debug it further? Or is there a known issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

You have not advised where the ISEC tunnel is terminated on the client side, nor how it is set up, and this knowledge will be needed to provide a more precise answer.

The issue you are having would be a connectivity one - the Macbook is unable to achieve a connection to the server.   It could be because the IPSEC tunnel is incorrectly configured, or that its handing out the same resources (IP address) to both the MAC and Android device and routing the traffic to the Android device.